# Product verification using QRCODES

Tags: python, reactjs, flutter

I am working on a project that scan qrcodes on a product e.g Cup, and verify whether the product is the database or not, I have built the scanning app using Flutter, now my problem is creating QRCODES each having a unique identity or a specified URL that is linked to the database.

I have tried to search on the internet how I can do this but I am not finding useful answers any provided on this will be highly appreciated thanks in advance!

Comment: On which platform (with what programming lang) do you want to create a QR code?

Comment: @boformer I would like to use any python and if possible use django for handling data inputs and firebase realtime database for storage of information, but any suggestions are welcome as long as they help achieve my aim thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use Phyton, I can recommend [this library](https://pythonhosted.org/PyQRCode/) for QR Code creation and rendering.

I'm not sure if you can connect Firebase with a Phyton app, it would probably easier to write a pure Angular/React/Vue web app.

Regarding the unique IDs. I'm not sure who is scanning the items. It might be a good idea to generate a URL QR Code, so if people scan the code with a different app, they get redirected to your website (maybe displaying help information how to scan the code).

For example: `https://example.com/help/product-scan?pid=<the actual product id>`

You can use any ID that can be stored in a database, e.g.:

- A human-readable string identifier, e.g. `octocat_cup`
- Numeric value, like an autogenerated key from a SQL database
- UUID v4 (great for distributed systems and offline usage)

Comment: thanks for your response and suggestion sorry I wasn't clear in my explanation, in my case a users will be using a mobile application which I have already built to scan a physical item e.g a cup, then an app application will query the database and return the results to the user on the mobile app itself

Comment: If my answer was helpful, you may want to accept it.